# Árvore Binária com percurso Em-Ordem e Pré-Ordem

Tags: python, estrutura-de-dados, recursão, árvore-binária

Estou com algumas dúvidas do percurso tomado por essa árvore binária:

1. Poderia classificar ela como binária? Visto que ela tem nós com 3 folhas?

   ```
   T=(35,(80,(7,(11,(12)),(15,(6,(0),(1),(2)),(9))),(3,(18),(8))),(73,(13),(27),(61)))
   ```
2. Estaria correto afirmar que os percursos são esses?

   Pré-Ordem:

   ```
   35,80,7,11,12,15,6,0,1,2,9,3,18,8,73,13,27,71
   ```

   Em-Ordem:

   ```
   12,11,0,1,2,6,9,15,7,18,8,3,80,35,13,27,71,73
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nessa notação, uma sequência do tipo `(A,(B),(C))` significa que `A` é um nó que tem como filhos as subárvores `B` e `C`.

Vamos desenhar essa árvore:

[image: (35,(80,(7,(11,(12)),(15,(6,(0),(1),(2)),(9))),(3,(18),(8))),(73,(13),(27),(61)))]

1. Numa árvore binária, nenhum nó pode ter mais do que dois filhos. O `(6,(0),(1),(2))` e o `(73,(13),(27),(61))` que estão lá no meio claramente são violações disso, por representarem nós com três filhos. O nó 11 não tem filho direito, apenas o esquerdo.
2. A busca em pré-ordem consiste em ao visitar cada nó, primeiro visitar o número nele contido e depois a subárvore da esquerda e por último a da direita. Recursivamente. No caso de haver mais do que dois filhos, eles devem ser visitados da esquerda para a direita. A notação dada `(A,(B),(C))` já vai representar a árvore em pré-ordem, e portanto o resultado da visita dos nós vai ser a mesma sequência na qual eles aparecem nessa notação, não importando o local em que estão na árvore. Assim sendo, o resultado é então: **35, 80, 7, 11, 12, 15, 6, 0, 1, 2, 9, 3, 18, 8, 73, 13, 27 e 61**. Sua resposta está quase correta, o único detalhe é que o último número é 61 ao invés de 71.
3. A busca em-ordem consiste em ao visitar cada nó, primeiro visitar o filho esquerdo, depois o próprio nó e depois o filho direito. Recursivamente. Consiste em substituir `(A,(B),(C))` por `((B),A,(C))`.

   No caso de um nó `(A,(B),(C),(D))` que tem mais do que dois filhos, não é claro o que deve ser feito, uma vez que a visita em-ordem só é definida para os casos onde há não mais que dois filhos. Há duas possibilidades aqui: substituir `(A,(B),(C),(D))` por `((B),A,(C),(D))` ou por `((B),(C),A,(D))`. Isso significa que o `(6,(0),(1),(2))` poderia ser visitado como 0, 6, 1, 2 ou como 0, 1, 6, 2.

   A ordem resultante seria **12, 11, 7, 0, [1 e 6], 2, 15, 9, 80, 18, 3, 8, 35, 13, [73 e 27], 61**. Os números no formato [A e B] podem ser permutados dependendo se você quiser usar `((B),A,(C),(D))` ou `((B),(C),A,(D))`.

   O que você parece estar querendo é a vista em **pós-ordem** que é a de visitar o nó só após os filhos serem visitados. Consistem em trocar `(A,(B),(C))` por `((B),(C),A)`. Essa ordenação produz um resultado parecido com o que você propôs, apenas com o 35 no final e com 61 no lugar de 71. A visita em pós-ordem seria **12, 11, 0, 1, 2, 6, 9, 15, 7, 18, 8, 3, 80, 13, 27, 61, 73 e 35**.

Uma forma de entender a ordenação é vendo o esquema abaixo:

[image: árvore com setas]

As visitas ocorrem no trajeto da sequência indicada pelas setas, contornando a árvore. Neste trajeto, cada nó pode ser visitado pela esquerda, por baixo ou pela direita. As setas que chegam nos nós pela esquerda são as verdes, as que chegam por baixo são as amarelas e as que chegam pela direita são as vermelhas.

Se você considerar apenas as setas verdes, estará fazendo visita em pré-ordem. Se considerar apenas as amarelas, estará fazendo a visita em-ordem. Se considerar apenas as vermelhas, estará fazendo em pós-ordem.

Observe que no caso da visita em-ordem, um mesmo nó é acessado mais de uma vez por baixo se houver mais do que dois filhos (no caso, o 6 e o 73), vez que essa situação é ambígua nessa circunstância.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Victor!!!!!! Estava com dificuldade a dias, você me ajudou. Espero poder retribuir, grato!